# Live Activities with UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have an app that uses UIKit, and I'd like to add Live Activites support to it. I started a new project that makes full use of SwiftUI. It has Live Activities that work perfectly, and all of the functions work properly.

However...

When I launch my app in UIKit, I generate a new SwiftUI File and a new Widget Target. I copied the exact codes into my app and was able to open a SwiftUI view with the UIHostingController. No problem, but when I press the "Run Live Activities" button, I see a white border on Dynamic Island but nothing else. There are no Live Activites displayed on the lock screen. I've already added Support Live Activities to the list and set it to YES. What did I overlook?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the Dynamic Island? And does the console show any interesting logs?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this in the meantime?

Comment: Hello, I think I found out that Live Activities doesn't support UIKit app because of I am not allowed to have two @main. I think has to be SwiftUI app only.